# Computing mean and variance of numpy memmap Infinity output

Tags: python, numpy, memory

Creation of memmap  array:

```
  out = np.memmap('my_array.mmap', dtype=np.float16, mode='w+', shape=(num_axis1, num_axis2))
  for index,row in enumerate(temp_train_data):
        __,cd_i=pywt.dwt(X_train[index:index+1001].ravel(),'haar')
        out[index]=(cd_i)
(Pdb) out.shape
(1421392L, 3504L)
```

Now, I simply feature scale this array. Subtract by mean and divide by variance.

```
np.mean(out[:,1])
memmap(inf, dtype=float16)
```

The output is 
`memmap(inf, dtype=float16)`
I don't understand why!

Reproducible example:

```
import numpy as np
ut = np.memmap('my_array.mmap', dtype=np.float16, mode='w+',\
  shape=(140000, 3504))
for index,row in enumerate(ut):
    ut[index]=np.random.rand(1,3504)*10
print np.max(ut[:,1])
print np.mean(ut[:,1],axis=0)
```

> 10.0
>
> inf

Comment: you may want to give a little more information here and create a working code example...

Comment: Since I dont know your sample data: You did not provide an axis to `np.mean`, therefore calculating an average over all elements in your slice. If there is any infinite value in there, the output may well show `inf` as well...

Comment: @dux please check again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format#Precision_limitations_on_integer_values), the `float16` data type can't handle integers larger than 65520. The sum of all the values in your collection is probably larger than that, so it gets rounded up to infinity when calculating the mean.

Consider using a data type that has a higher upper limit. For example, `float32`.

```
ut = np.memmap('my_array.mmap', dtype=np.float32, mode='w+',\
  shape=(140000, 3504))
```

When I make this change, I get some nice non-infinite output:

```
9.99996471405
4.9927
```

---

Alternatively, if you really have to have a `float16` array, you can specify the type used to calculate the mean:

```
print np.mean(ut[:,1],axis=0,dtype=np.float32)
```

Comment: thanks for clear explanation. But that would exceed my memory. Could it be possible just to set the variable aggregating through the array of a different data type. That save a lot of memory.

Comment: Hmm, in that case you could probably do `print np.mean(ut[:,1],axis=0,dtype=np.float32)`.

Comment: Thanks so much! @Kevin.